# firebase serve - React Context returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm currently facing a problem with a firebase deployment, happening only in production environment. **I cannot reproduce it in local**, with the `firebase serve` command; even if I'm using the target 6.11.5 node version.

Here is my trouble : when deployed, the site will crash (server-side) rendering **a React component using a Context's return property**

Component extract :

```
<div className='rank-item col-sm-6 col-lg-3'>
    <LangContext.Consumer>
      {
        ({ lang, langs }) => (
          // here, props are cools in development
          //   but are undefined in production
        )
      }
    </LangContext.Consumer>
</div>
```

App root component (at this point, `props.lang` & `props.langs` are correctly set, even on production environment) :

```
export default props => (
  <LangContext.Provider value={ {
      lang: props.lang,
      langs: props.langs
  } }>
  </LangContext.Provider>
)
```

The problem as shown in the console :

[image: firebase console log]

As you may have guess, **I'm building my SSR code with webpack to commonjs2 module**. The error stack trace here refers to this exact line of built code :

[image: built code line target]

I'm a bit surprised because I already used React's Context feature on a production environment, but cannot figure now what could be the problem. Thanks for your help